subset dplyr dataframe with custom rule
I have a dataframe like the following:
df <- data.frame(num = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10), value = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'))

I would like to subset the dataframe by rows that are continuous (serial) without break. My output should look like the following:
    num value
1     1     a
2     2     b
3     4     c
4     5     d
5     9     f
6    10     g

With the code below,
df_subset = df %>% 
  mutate(difference = num - lag(num, default = first(num))) %>%
  filter(difference ==1 | row_number() ==1)

The output excludes 4 & 9
   num value
1     1     a
2     2     b
3     5     d
4    10     g

because the value of difference is not 1. How to modify this to create the groups with series?

You could use diff twice instead of lags:
df %>%
  filter(c(1, diff(num))==1 | c(diff(num), NA)==1)


  num value
1   1     a
2   2     b
3   4     c
4   5     d
5   9     f
6  10     g


Great! Basically, you combine two mutate and filter in one line!

In collapse, you can use seqid to create an id for each group of serial rows. Retrieve the group sizes with GRPN, and keep rows whose group size is 2 or more.
library(collapse)
df[GRPN(seqid(df$num)) > 1, ]

#   num value
# 1   1     a
# 2   2     b
# 3   4     c
# 4   5     d
# 5   9     f
# 6  10     g

You can also use collapse in the dplyr framework:
df |> 
  filter(GRPN(seqid(num)) > 1)

